# Need help on MYSQL query returning common rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an example table as such:

```
Year, Make, Model
1991 Honda Accord
1992 Honda Accord
1993 Honda Accord
1993 Ford Explorer
```

If I want to get all the Makes that are in production from 1992-1993, the returned rows should be "Honda", since Ford(in my example) only produced one car in 1993, but not one in 1992.

Any ideas on the query I can use?

EDIT:

Using the query from the answer below to use IN statements, does work, but when I do 25 IN statements, the time it takes is too long and it times out.

I tested it starting like 1990 1991, and then 1990 1991 1992, etc... when it gets around 2000 it takes too long and times out. I do have the choice of just doing two years(begin year, and end year) but I fear that wont be as accurate, as a manufacturer could have products a car in the beginning year parameter, and even the end year parameter, but have NOT produced a car somewhere in  between, and even worse, when I start doing this with Models instead of makes, I definitely HAVE to check all years.

**Table definition**

```
CREATE TABLE Cars
( year INT,
  Make VARCHAR(20),
  Model VARCHAR(20)
 );
```

**Table Data**

```
INSERT INTO Cars
SELECT 1991, 'Alfo', 'Rom'
UNION
SELECT 1992, 'Alfo', 'Rom'
UNION
SELECT 1993, 'Alfa', 'Rom'
UNION
SELECT 1994, 'Alfa', 'Rom'
UNION
SELECT 1992, 'Honda', 'Accord'
UNION
SELECT 1993, 'Honda', 'Accord'
UNION
SELECT 1994, 'Honda', 'Del Sol'
UNION
SELECT 1993, 'Acura', 'Integra'
UNION
SELECT 1994, 'Acura', 'TL'
UNION
SELECT 1993, 'Ford', 'Explorer'
UNION
SELECT 1994, 'Honda', 'Accord';
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3fc25)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tested it starting like 1990 1991, and then 1990 1991 1992, etc...
>   when it gets around 2000 it takes too long and times out. I do have
>   the choice of just doing two years(begin year, and end year) but I
>   fear that wont be as accurate, as a manufacturer could have products a
>   car in the beginning year parameter, and even the end year parameter,
>   but have NOT produced a car somewhere in between, and even worse, when
>   I start doing this with Models instead of makes, I definitely HAVE to
>   check all years.

You need to use `HAVING` and `COUNT`

```
SELECT  t.Make
FROM   
    (SELECT DISTINCT c.YEAR, c.Make
    FROM cars c) t 
WHERE t.YEAR IN (1992,1993,1994)  -- all the years
GROUP BY t.make
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3 --total number of years
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3fc25/4)

Comment: Hmm.. I get this response: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'c.Make' in 'field list'

Comment: did you update the table name in all three places? what is the name of the table?

Comment: Yes, I have definitely updated the table names. Name of my table is Cars. All 3 places. I'm using MYSQL 5.6 on windows

Comment: I am updating my answer you questions based on your [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26443964/need-help-on-mysql-query-returning-common-rows/26444150?noredirect=1#comment41531352_26444047). Please add the comment to the question

Comment: @davidmaster I updated the answer and added SQL fiddle for MYSQL 5.6  check it out

Comment: This is working, but returns wrong result set. Returns 2 makes, but should return about 15 during this year range.

Comment: This worked and returned very fast. I'm sorry I'm newbie so I am going to have to study your query and figure out how exactly it is working and why. I really appreciate this! The part that confuses me is the "c." and "t.". it seems these are creating variables some how. I have to go learn that

Comment: c and t are [alias](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) used for the table name

Comment: @davidmaster would it be fine if i update the question by adding your sample data ?

Comment: By all means, you can do whatever you like :)

Comment: I did suggest an update to your question you need to accept it. If you need I will add explanation about my code to the answer

Comment: Please consider up voting my answer as well. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Can I pay you for some teaching time? send me email davidfes88@yahoo.com :)

Comment: You need not pay me let me know when you need help If I have time I will help you. I am good at SQL only.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of `in` operators will do the trick:

```
SELECT make
FROM   my_table
WHERE  make IN (SELECT make 
                FROM   my_table
                WHERE  year = 1992) AND
       make IN (SELECT make 
                FROM   my_table
                WHERE  year = 1993)
```

Comment: Perfect! You are awesome. I didn't know about the IN operator. :D I am now super happy.

Comment: @mureninik There's another issue now. If I do a long range of years, say 1990-2015, the return takes too long and mysql times out. I tested it starting like 1990 1991, and then 1990 1991 1992, etc... when it gets around 2000 it takes too long and times out. I do have the choice of just doing two years(begin year, and end year) but I fear that wont be as accurate, as a manufacturer could have NOT produced a car in that certain year.